# How does MFC CDatabase::OpenEx function knows it is in try/catch block?

Tags: c++, exception, mfc

Consider next piece of code:

```
void CMyDB::Connect()
{
    //db_ is an member object of CDatabase class
    //connStr is previously defined connection string
    db_.OpenEx(connStr, CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);
}
```

after executing `Connect()` -- if connection string contained wrong data, then a message box with error description will be shown.

Now if I wrap that call to `Connect()` in try/catch block no message box will be shown, instead an exception will be thrown:

```
void CMyDB::Connect()
{
    try {
        result = db_.OpenEx(connStr, CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);
    }
    catch(CDBException* e) { }
}
```

Now, I don't understand how `OpenEx()` understands that it is being wrapped by try/catch block and there is no need to show message box with error description. I know it somehow related to those MFC specific macro used inside `OpenEx()` (TRY, CATCH_ALL, etc.) and an AFX_EXCEPTION_LINK structure provided by them, but still can't get the whole picture.

Thanks.

Comment: You catch ans swallow the error. The MessageBox was probably shown by a top-level catch.

Comment: @quantdev yeah it seems you are right, strange I didn't consider top-catch level. Please, write your comment as question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't know it.

Your `catch` does swallow the exception, which was (before you add the `try/catch`) thrown to a top-level catch in your program. This top level catch was showing the Dialog Box with the error message.